# Программа на C выдает ошибку SIGTRAP на realloc в цикле while

Tags: c, память, malloc, realloc

очень простой пример: в цикле while увеличивается размер динамического строкового массива на единицу. Возникает ошибка в строке с realloc (при втором проходе). Причем даже нет возможности проверить tmp на NULL! Сразу кидается исключение.
Как же правильно увеличивать длину строки динамически?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n=1,delta=1;
    char* tmp=(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
    if (tmp==NULL) return 0;

    while(n<=10){
        n+=delta;
        tmp=realloc(tmp,(n)*sizeof(char));  //error!!!
        if (tmp==NULL) {free(tmp);return 0;}
        for(int i=0,j=48;i<n-1;i++,j++)
        printf("%c",tmp[i-1]=j);
        tmp[n-1]='\0';
    }
    free(tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В чем смысл этого действия: `if (tmp==NULL) {free(tmp);... }`? И опять этот странный карго-культ: на `malloc` стоит приведение типа (ненужное), а на `realloc` его нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0,j=48;i<n-1;i++,j++)
    printf("%c",tmp[i-1]=j);
```

Скажите, **куда** вы пишете `tmp[i-1]=j` при **первой** итерации, когда `i` равно 0?

Выход за границы, UB...